# .net MVC web app using Angular and Node js along with Entity Framework

Tags: sql, angularjs, node.js, entity-framework, model-view-controller

Is it recommended to use Angular js + Node js + Entity Framework to use in a .net MVC application?

Comment: As far as I now, NodeJS could not call Entity Framework. You might want to consider Angular + WebAPI + EntityFramework if you want to use .Net.

Comment: So in order to use Node js and Angularjs both i need vomit EF? and use Node js to communicate with SQL?

Comment: Yes, forget about EF if you plan to use Node. Instead, you want to connect straight to SQL from Node, so Angular + Node + SQL.

Answer (score 0):

As other people already said. You won't be able to use Entity Framework.
You should consider using MongoDB as a database. And Mongoose for management.

Check this for the beginning:

https://scotch.io/tutorials/using-mongoosejs-in-node-js-and-mongodb-applications

http://mherman.org/blog/2015/08/24/node-express-swig-mongo-primer/#.WDyTi_nhCUk